# Set up ido mode in emacs 21

Tags: emacs, ido-mode

I am using ido mode. and GNUM emacs 21.1.1 on AIX.
I add the ido.el in the .emacs.d. and add the following in the .emacs file.

```
(load-file "~/.emacs.d/site-lisp/ido/ido.el")
(require 'ido)
(ido-mode t)
(setq ido-enable-flex-matching t) ;; enable fuzzy matching
```

When start emacs, it complains. and there is no ido-mode.
How to fix this?

```
error: "Unknown req `min-colors' with options `(88)'"

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate the cause
of the error in your initialization file and remove it.  Start
Emacs with the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error
backtrace
```

contents of the backtrace

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Unknown req `min-colors' with options `(88)'")
  signal(error ("Unknown req `min-colors' with options `(88)'"))
  error("Unknown req `%S' with options `%S'" min-colors (88))
  face-spec-set-match-display(((min-colors 88) (class color)) #<frame F1 0x201a3600\ >)
  face-spec-choose((((... ...) (:foreground "red1")) ((...) (:foreground "red")) (t (:underline t))) #<frame F1 0x201a3600\ >)
  face-spec-set(ido-subdir (((... ...) (:foreground "red1")) ((...) (:foreground "red")) (t (:underline t))) #<frame F1 0x201a3600\ >)
  custom-declare-face(ido-subdir (((... ...) (:foreground "red1")) ((...) (:foreground "red")) (t (:underline t))) "Face used by ido for highlighting subdirs in the alternatives." :group ido)
  (defface ido-subdir (quote (... ... ...)) "Face used by ido for highlighting subdirs in the alternatives." :group (quote ido))
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*<2>> nil "~/.emacs.d/site-lisp/ido/ido.el" nil t)
  load-with-code-conversion("~/.emacs.d/site-lisp/ido/ido.el" "~/.emacs.d/site-lisp/ido/ido.el" nil nil)
  load("~/.emacs.d/site-lisp/ido/ido.el" nil nil t)
  load-file("~/.emacs.d/site-lisp/ido/ido.el")
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "~/.emacs" nil t)
  load-with-code-conversion("~/.emacs" "~/.emacs" t t)
  load("~/.emacs" t t)
  #[nil "^H\205\227^@   Æ=\203^Q^@Ç^HÈQ\2025^@  É=\203'^@ÊÇËÌ#\203#^@Í\2025^@Î\2025^@   Ï=\2031^@Ð\2025^@Ç^HÑQ^ZÒ^SÓ\nÒ\211#\210^KÒ=\203F^@Ë^S^K\203\210^@Ô^K!Õ\232\203\210^@Ö^K!\211^\×P^]Ø^M!\203d$
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

Comment: `emacs --debug-init` and paste the contents of the backtrace.

Comment: Looks like you should post this on the ido mailing list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem.  We're upgrading to RHEL5, so I assume we'll have emacs 21 for a long time.  Luckily the EmacsWiki has a link to an [older version](http://www.cua.dk/).  It's over a decade old, but it's better than nothing.

It seems to work fine, but some of the constants have different names.  For example, I had set ido-default-file-method to selected-window, but the latter is named same-window in the older version of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Emacs 21.1.1 is fairly ancient (21.1 was released almost exactly 10 years ago). Upgrade to a more recent version, and you should be fine (unless it no longer builds on AIX?) Lots of people are using the not-yet-final version 24, but 23.3 is the current stable release.

ido is also a standard part of Emacs, these days, so you should be able to get rid of your copy of that.

Admittedly you may well encounter other upgrade incompatibilities by taking this approach, but that issue will surely only get worse as time goes on...